# materialize nested cols layout

Tags: css, layout, materialize

I am trying for 2 days to do this layout:

[image: Layout]

Is it possible to get the materialize grid to display the layout in the image.
If so, please help if you can & kindly give some hints.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col s3">Content 1 </div>
      <div class="col s6">Content 2 </div>
      <div class="col s3">Formmmm</div>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col s3">Content 3 </div>
      <div class="col s6">Content 4 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Abd elhedi. Didnt know such a nesting was possible.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this as a container that has two columns. The first column contains content1 to 4 and the second contains Form.
In the first column create two rows each with two columns. The first row has content1 and 2 and the second row contains Content3 and 4.
Like this

```
<div class container>
  <div class="row parent-row">
     <div class="col s8 m8 l8 first-col">
       <!-- this contains content1 to 4 -->
       <div class="row row-1">
           <div class="col s4 m4 l4 content-1">
              Content 1
           </div>
           <div class="col s4 m4 l4 content-2">
              Content 2
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row row-2">
            <div class="col s4 m4 l4 content-3">
              Content 3
           </div>
           <div class="col s4 m4 l4 content-4">
              Content 4
           </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col s4 m4 l4 second-col">
         Form
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that in order to make the Form Column (second-col) to be the same height as first-col Column of Content1 to Content4 regardless of the content. You will have to add styling using flex.

```
.parent-row{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
//some where in project.css
```

Also note that you can use vh in css3 to force heights that you want.

```
.second-col{
  height:100vh;
}
.row-1{
  height:50vh;
}
.row-2{
  height:50vh;
}
```

Finally you have to note how the col widths add up to 12 in all cases accross. E.g for first-col we have s8 as width and its children. content-1 and content-2 add up to s8 ==> s4+s4.
While first-col and second-col add up to s12 ==> (s8 + s4)